# parsing data with pugi library in c++

Tags: c++, svg

I have a problem parsing document with pugi lib in c++.
I'm completely new to parsing in c++.
Here is my svg file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.9.1 -->
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='260.973912pt' height='53.742909pt' viewBox='229.120747 -42.285873 260.973912 53.742909'>
<defs>
<font id='cmr10' horiz-adv-x='0'>
<font-face font-family='cmr10' units-per-em='1000' ascent='750' descent='250'/>
</font>
<font id='cmmi10' horiz-adv-x='0'>
<font-face font-family='cmmi10' units-per-em='1000' ascent='750' descent='250'/>
</font>
</defs>
<style type='text/css'>
<![CDATA[text.f0 {font-family:cmmi10;font-size:9.96264px}
text.f1 {font-family:cmr10;font-size:9.96264px}
]]>
</style>
<g id='page1'>
<text class='f1' x='485.11332' y='-35.865504'>1</text>
<text class='f0' x='229.120747' y='11.457036'>abc</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

And here is my code:

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"
#include "pugixml.cpp"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string svg_file_path = "path_to_file.xml";
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(svg_file_path.c_str(), pugi::parse_default | pugi::parse_declaration);
    pugi::xml_node root = doc.document_element();
    return 0;
}
```

However when I debug I see that the variable root is still undefined. In the meantime, the value of pugi::parse_default is recognized as 116U while the value of pugi::parse_declaration is recognized as 256U.
For the  result variable it writes status = status_ok(0)

What could I possible do wrong? How do I access such things as content of  children? Their class (f0, f1) or finally, data  CDATA where I need to know the correspondence {"f0": "cmmi10"} and {"f1": "cmr10"}
?

Yaroslav.

Comment: Off-topic, but why are you including one `.cpp` file into another? This `#include "pugixml.cpp"` line is not correct.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claim that the `root` variable remains undefined. Where do you set a breakpoint to inspect `root`? You need to set a breakpoint at the `return 0` line, otherwise the execution will not yet reach the point where `root` is initialized.

Comment: Indeed, you were right. Thanks!